# how to download WWDC 2010 video now by curl or wget?

Tags: ios, curl, wget, wwdc

for example : https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_122__accessibility_on_iphone_os.mov

when i enter

`curl https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_122__accessibility_on_iphone_os.mov > ~/Desktop/122.mov`

or

`wget https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_122__accessibility_on_iphone_os.mov > ~/Desktop/122.mov`

Both failed, only download a 333KB file.

Answer (score 0):

The mov file you get is only a reference file which is used to select to correct files for your network connection.

You could try `mplayer <url> -dumpstream -dumpfile <filename>` if you have an mplayer.

You could also open the file and find the filename to the correct real file.

Also you could write some script to parse the reference file.
Here is a function I wrote in perl to parse a mov ref file:

```
sub parseMov
{
    $uri = $_[0];
    $result_uri = "";
    @arr_uris = ();

    my $content = get $uri;

    $content =~ "/[^[:print:]]//g";

    @arr_movs = split("rmdr", $content);

    foreach (@arr_movs)
    {   
       @arr_parts = split("url", $_);
       my $file = $arr_parts[-1];

       if (index($file, ".mov") != -1 || index($file, ".3gp") != -1 || index($file, ".m4v") != -1) 
       {
           #remove first char
           $file = trim($file);
           $file = substr($file,4);
           push( @arr_uris, $file);
       }
   }

   #determine basePath
   my @pathComponents = split("/", $uri);
   $basePath = $uri;
   $basePath =~ s/$pathComponents[-1]//;

   my $biggestSize = 0;

   #get biggest file
   foreach (@arr_uris)
   {
       $uri_item = "$basePath$_";

       my $size = getFilesize($uri_item);

       if ($size > $biggestSize)
       {
          $finalURL = $uri_item;
          $biggestSize = $size;
       }

   }

   #remove %00 and %10 chars
   $finalURL =~ s/\x10//;
   $finalURL =~ s/\x00*//g;

   return $finalURL;
```

}

Comment: thank you very much. I run the script you type here. A error message come out "Can't locate object method "get" via package", any advise?

Comment: You need to install LWP try the following on a terminal `cpan install LWP HTTP::Request`